# Moveing files with java

Tags: java

I'm trying to move files using this java code and it can locate the file but not move it, just deletes the directory I'm moving it to.

```
public void ch() throws Exception{
   if (FC.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
       java.io.File file = FC.getSelectedFile();
       Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
       System.out.println(file);

       Path source = Paths.get(file + "");
       Path target = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Marcus\\Desktop\\2");       
       try {
           Files.move(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
       } catch (IOException e){ 
           System.out.println("Failed to move the file");
       }
   }else{
       System.out.println("?");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Files.move(), your target path should probably be the full path of the target file, not the destination directory where you want to place it.

```
Path target = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Marcus\\Desktop\\2\\" + source.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the file name at the end of your destination path, like below:
You could move files with File.ranameTo() method, like this:

```
file.renameTo(new File("C:\\Users\\Marcus\\Desktop\\2\\"+file.getName()));
```

In your example:

```
public void ch() throws Exception{
       if (FC.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
           java.io.File file = FC.getSelectedFile();      
           try {
                 file.renameTo(new File("C:\\Users\\Marcus\\Desktop\\2\\"+file.getName()));
           } catch (Exception e){ 
               System.out.println("Failed to move the file");
           }
       }else{
           System.out.println("?");
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Files.copy()` instead of `Files.move()`.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend the use of a third party tool such as Apache Commons IO's FileUtil class for this type of operation.

For example: [FileUtil.moveFileToDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFileToDirectory(java.io.File%20,%20java.io.File,%20boolean))

Using these types of utilities saves you from many problems you aren't even aware are lurking.  Yes, there are limitations to these common utils, but the benefits usually outweigh them in simple cases.

Google Guava is also an option, but I've got less experience there.

Comment: If a developer can use a core Java API, why would you recommend using a third party library?  `java.nio.file.Files` will perform the operation just fine without the need for a third party jar.

Comment: It's possible I'm just old school and like the tools I'm comfortable with :-D  But, I'd suggest semantic clarity favours the Apache utils.  You know 100% what's happening and your args are validated for you with the moveToDirectory() call.  It seems that's part of what the OP was tripping over in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close but there a couple of potential issues.  Before I start, I should say that I'm using a Mac (hence the path change), so while this is working for me, there may be some underlying permission issue on your system I can't account for.

1) You aren't using the name of the file you want to move to.  You're using the directory you want to move the file to.  That's a fair assumption, but you need to make it the fully qualified path *and* file name.

2) You are creating a `Scanner` to the to file but not using it.  This probably doesn't really matter, but it's best to eliminate unnecessary code.

3) You don't validate the path that was created by getting the `Path` instance returned from `Files.move()`.

Here is my example code.  I tested it and it worked fine.  Again, I'm using a Mac, so take that into account.

```
public void moveFile(){
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser("/");

    if (fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println("Chosen File: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

        String newFileName = System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+file.getName();
        System.out.println("Attempting to move chosen file to destination: " + newFileName);

        Path target = Paths.get(newFileName);

        try {
            Path newPath = Files.move(file.toPath(), target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
            System.out.println("Path returned from move: " + newPath);

        } catch (IOException e){
            // Checked exceptions are evil.
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to move the file: " + file.getAbsolutePath(),e);
        }
    }
}
```

The output from one of the tests:

```
Chosen File: /Users/dombroco/temp/simpleDbToFileTest1.txt
Attempting to move chosen file to destination: /Users/dombroco/simpleDbToFileTest1.txt
Path returned from move: /Users/dombroco/simpleDbToFileTest1.txt
```